# How do i link 2 teams into an overall plan on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have got 2 teams one dealing with Bug Fixes the other dealing with small enhancements and have created these 2 teams in VSTS.

I am now trying to plan the work for 2018 so that we have a guide on how much work we can schedule into the releases throughout the year.

I am trying to link the 2 teams and the work into the overall plan so that if (for example) we get more bugs than usual we can demonstrate what that is going to do to the overall plan as this will impact against the ability to deliver small enhancements as bug fixes will take priority.

Comment: If you have two separate teams, one working on bug fixes and one on enhancements, how can having extra bugs affect the enhancements team? Do they share a backlog? Are they put on bug fixing if required?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Portfolio Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/portfolio-management) settings of VSTS. This allows you to specify work at a higher level such as epics and features and then distribute the work across multiple teams.

You can then use the [Delivery Plans](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans) extension to plan work across multiple sprints.